# Код,приведенный из книги, почему то не хочет запускаться,объясните почему?

Tags: python

```
allGuests = {'Alice': {'apples': 5, 'pretzels': '12'},
             'Bob': {'sendwiches': '3', 'apples': '12'},
             'Carol': {'cups': '3', 'apple pies': '1'}}


def totalBrought(guests, item):
    numBrought = 0
    for k, v in guests.items():
        numBrought = numBrought + v.get(item, 0)
        return numBrought


print('Number of things being brought: ')
print(' - Apples        ' + str(totalBrought(allGuests, 'apples')))
print(' - Cups          ' + str(totalBrought(allGuests, 'cups')))
print(' - Sendwiches    ' + str(totalBrought(allGuests, 'sendwiches')))
print(' - Pretzels      ' + str(totalBrought(allGuests, 'pretzels')))
```

Вывод:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/eeNNdd11/PycharmProjects/course python/Что с собой принесли гости.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(' - Pretzels      ' + str(totalBrought(allGuests, 'pretzels')))
  File "C:/Users/eeNNdd11/PycharmProjects/course python/Что с собой принесли гости.py", line 9, in totalBrought
    numBrought = numBrought + v.get(item, 0)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 2):

Учитесь читать текст ошибки! Там всегда указано, в чем именно проблема.

Вот тут, например:

```
{'apples': 5, 'pretzels': '12'}
```

В этом коде `5` - число 5, а `'12'` не число 12, а текст "12". И так у вас везде напутано. А числа и текст сложить никак нельзя.

Comment: Исправил ошибку с типами данных, но вывод всей программы таков:
Number of things being brought: 
 - Apples        5
 - сups          0
 - Sendwiches    0
 - Pretzels      12

в словаре указано, что cups = 3, а вывод, их 0, не могли бы объяснить почему?

Answer (score 1):

У Вас типы данных разные, нужно вот так:

```
allGuests = {'Alice': {'apples': 5, 'pretzels': 12},
             'Bob': {'sendwiches': 3, 'apples': 12},
             'Carol': {'cups': 3, 'apple pies': 1}}
```

Comment: Исправил ошибку с типами данных, но вывод всей программы таков:
Number of things being brought: 
 - Apples        5
 - сups          0
 - Sendwiches    0
 - Pretzels      12

в словаре указано, что cups = 3, а вывод, их 0, не могли бы объяснить почему?

Comment: @Vyacheslav Bondarev   "return numBrought" стоит не на месте. Должно находится на одном уровне с for, а как у Вас, итерация выполняется только один раз для первого значения k, v.